# Thread priority in Producer-Consumer program - wait() & notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

Below I have included the Producer-Consumer program (from Java - The Complete Reference Guide Ninth Edition) which is probably a familiar example of inter-thread communication to many of you.

```
class Q {
     int n;
     boolean valueSet = false;

     synchronized int get() {
         while(!valueSet)
              try {
                  wait();
              } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                  System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
              }
         valueSet = false;
         notify();
         return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        while(valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        notify();
        }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Q q;
    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
     Q q;
     Consumer(Q q) {
         this.q = q;
         new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
     }
     public void run() {
         while(true) {
             q.get();
         }
     }
}

class PC {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
}
```

I would like clarification on why Producer can never modify *n* twice without Consumer returning. In  particular, inside *get*, the *notify();* line comes before *return n;*. (Of course the method must end with the return line.)

But, inside *get*, why can't the operating system award the lock to Producer after the line *notify()* and before *return n*?

Comment: They're not both active at the same time. One is inside a `synchronized` method, and the other is blocked waiting to get in.

Comment: Sorry, by active I mean not suspended by wait().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why is it inconceivable that the Producer thread gets to this.n = n; before the Consumer thread executes the very next return n; line, on say a single core system?

Because, both methods are `synchronized` and only one thread can execute them at one time.

For your scenario, if CPU puts away consumer thread after calling `notify()` and before returning `n`; producer will still be waiting to acquire lock due to `synchronized` keyword. Producer has become runnable after call to `notify` but will not run until lock remains with consumer.

Comment: My understanding was that if a thread owns a lock it *can* yield before the method returns, but sometimes the operating system will preemptively allocate the monitor to another thread.

Comment: Yes, There are synchronized methods and synchronized blocks. in latter case, thread can relinquish the lock before method returns. And, `wait()` method can be understood as a signal to OS that -- preempt current thread and monitor can be allocated to another thread.

Comment: Ah. So basically the thread which owns the lock will always get to the end of a synchronized method, unless 'wait()' is called inside the method. Notify will not yield the lock, it just means that after this thread is finished with the method, the other thread is no longer suspended. 

Is this accurate? ^

Comment: Great! Thank you Azodious :)

Answer (score 0):

*While a thread is inside a synchronized method, all other threads that try to call it (or any other synchronized method) on the same instance have to wait.* [Reference: The Complete Reference: Java]

Here, if the Consumer thread is inside the get() method, Producer thread will have to wait before calling put() method till Consumer finishes executing get() method because both methods are **syncronized** and called on the **same instance q**.